# Task scheduling Batch Files in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, batch, scheduled-tasks

Wondering if there is some trick to scheduling a batch file to run in Vista.

I have tried almost every setting/arg I can think of with no result other than an error, or the command window opening then instantly closing without executing the code.

The batch files works fine when I double click to run.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the issue.

If you have a batch file you want to run, the path to the batch file can not have any spaces in it (even if you include quotes).

Putting the batch file in C:\ allowed it to run via Task Scheduler.

Comment: Sounds weird. I know the scheduler dialog is rather stupid like you should include quotes in the script path (browse:able) but exclude the quotes for the "start in" field...

Answer (score 2):

Does the task scheduler in control panel not work?

You can also use `at` from the command line. If you want your script to be interactive and be visible to the user, you can use the `/interactive` switch:

```
at 20:00 /interactive c:\path\to\somefile.bat
```

this will open the command prompt at 8pm.

For finer control over the scheduling you can use `schtasks`:

```
SCHTASKS /Create /SC MONTHLY /MO first /D SUN /TN game /TR c:\windows\system32\freecell
```

Comment: yes, the default task scheduler does not work.

using schtasks, I still get the same issue, where the command prompt simply opens then closes without executing the batch commands.

Comment: what about `at` ?

Answer (score 0):

To work around this problem, enclose the path portion of the task (not including arguments or switches) between backslash (\) and quotation marks (") character combinations, for example \". Enclose the complete path of the task (including arguments or switches) between quotation marks as usual when you create a path or command that contains spaces.

```
schtasks /create /tn "my task" /tr "\"c:\foldername name containing spaces\script.bat\" arguments" /sc once /sd 07/29/2003 /st 10:01
```

source: [support.microsoft.com](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B823093&x=19&y=7)